# Jquery over facebook , twitter , google plus iframe?

Tags: php, facebook, twitter

I want to run/execute jquery code on facebook, twitter, google plus iframe. 
I have tried to do it in many ways but it is not working. 
Code is always showing error none/object not found. 
Actually I want to know whether currently logged-in user has already done **like/follow/+** . 
If the current logged-in user has already done like/follow then I need to **hide like/follow** links,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the PHP Facebook SDK you can query it as follows:

```
 $likes = $facebook->api('me/likes');
 $fanpageliked = false;
 $appliked = false;

    foreach ($likes['data'] as $ilike) {
        if ($ilike['id'] == $fanpageid) {$fanpageliked = true;}
        if ($ilike['id'] == $appid) {$appliked = true; }
    }
```

If your fanpage id is stored in $fanpageid, or app id in $appid, then $fanpageliked will be true (and/or appid).

So if you are only looking for a fanpage id, remove the appid if and add a break:

```
 if ($ilike['id'] == $fanpageid) {
      $fanpageliked = true;
      break;
 }
```

After that, you can have the following:

```
if (!$fanpageliked) {
    echo "Like us NOW!";
    // .... display like button etc
   }
else {
     echo "You are ours now. Bwa ha ha!";
   }
```

Comment: I have read the question. The poser of the question wants to know whether the currently logged on user has done a like or a follow. I showed them how to check for a follow. I didn't show how to do it in twitter because I don't know how to do it in twitter, and I found this question in the facebook section of stackoverflow. Better half an answer than none.

Comment: I meant this .. your response is wrong if the user isn't auth inside the website :) A wrong answer is just wrong.

Comment: Well, they did say "the currently logged on user", and I have taken that to mean they have logged on / are using your ap or website. Perhaps you need to address your concerns to the person who posted the question? It was phrased fairly vaguely.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with jquery but you can use their own APIs to accomplish what you need. Facebook for example already has all that in their API.

Comment: Try on developer's page from FB, after Facebook JS SDK : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/